# Force an image to ALWAYS stay at the middle of a div

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, center

I'm searching ways to force an image element to stay always aligned at the middle of a div even when the div element gets too small to properly center the image. Here's an explanation of what I want to do: [Question.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDfGh.jpg)

I need the solution to be purely CSS if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this centering trick should give you what you want:

```
img {
  position:relative; (or absolute, it depends on your needs)
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This keeps the image centered no matter the size of the container it is in. It doesn't resize the image though. Based on that pic you out it seems like you didn't want that.

Comment: Between all of the answers I've received you are pretty much near of what I want! It seems to work but I'm facing a little problem: what about the dimensions of the image? Actually I need something that works for every dimensions of images (portrait, paysage, cubic), you have any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I think if you remove the height of the div box, then remove "top:50%" from the img, then change "transform:translate(-50%, -50%)" to "transform:translateX(-50%)", you'll get an image that centers horizontally, and the div size will match the height of the image. Then you can add padding to the top and bottom of the image for space.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following grid layout and styles:

```
 style{
    .container{ max-width:800px; margin:0 auto;}

}

@media
only screen and (max-width:600px) {
.mCenter{margin:0 auto;}
.mImage600:{width:100%; height:auto;}
}

<div class=container>
<div class=mCenter>
<img class=mImage600 src 'img.jpg' width=600 >
</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5oc1zrv/)

```
img{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

could help

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, using display `flex`.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/323000/323026/angry-birds-theme-02-100x100.png" alt="">
</div>
```